# MongoDB, Control de ingresos / egresos. Me llega un registro por cada vez que marcan con el dedo

Tags: mongodb

Soy nuevo aquí, En MongoDB, me llegan marcas (un registro por cada marca) desde un lector de huellas, (el tema es que no se si cada vez que marca entra o sale alguien).
Ordenando los registros (marcas) de cada día (por hora), deseo poner un campo con un 0 para la primera, 1 para la segunda, un 0 para la tercera, un 1 para la cuarta y asi sucesivamente
Espero se comprenda y puedan ayudarme

Comment: Hola y bienvenidx a SOes. La mejor forma de lograr que se comprenda es usando un [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario.

Comment: ¿Y cómo sabes cuando es entrada o salida si el usuario hace turno de noche? Y si olvida registrar una salida o una entrada ¿Cómo sabes el orden? Lo que propones no es muy fiable

Comment: Gracias por responder. Justo "el problema" es no saber si entra o sale. Cada empleado tiene para cada día un horario, supongo que la primer marcación del día es ingreso, la segunda egreso, la 3 ingreso la 4 egreso y así sucesivamente. Si las marcaciones son impares emito mensaje de error. Acepto sugerencias, se que mi solucion no es muy solida, pero, "no veo" si entra o sale. Si "se olvida" enviare un mensaje de error